# error: Invalid input syntax for bigint type: "all" with the parameter "all.pdf" in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I set up a route that when placing all.pdf, it searches all the id's in the database, generates a pdf of each and joins it in only one pdf of several pages. But when I put all.pdf it returns the error: error: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "all"

I also have the parameter with the limit, if I put all/15.pdf (15 is the number of id's that will be pulled) it correctly pulls the 15 without any problem, but when I put all.pdf it returns this error. How can I solve?

```
router.get('/:database/:tipo/:ids/:limite?.pdf', async (req, res) => {
  const { database, tipo, ids, limite } = req.params;

  let idsArray;
  if (ids === "all") {
    const pool = new Pool({
      user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      database: database,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    });

    let query = `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM controle_interno.${tipo} ORDER BY id ASC`;
    if (limite) {
      query += ` LIMIT ${limite}`;
    }
    const result = await pool.query(query);
    idsArray = result.rows.map(row => row.id);
  } else {
    idsArray = ids.split(",");
  }

  const pdfs = [];
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  for (let i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
    const id = idsArray[i];
    const url = `http://localhost:${port}/${database}/${tipo}/${id}`;
    console.log(url);
    try {
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const button = document.getElementById('gerar-pdf');
      button.remove();
    });
  const pdfBytes = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4', printBackground: true, pageRanges: '1' });
  pdfs.push(await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes));
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
 }
}
  await browser.close();

  const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();
  for (const pdf of pdfs) {
    const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
    copiedPages.forEach((page) => mergedPdf.addPage(page));
  }

  const pdfBytes = await mergedPdf.save();
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'relatorio.pdf');

  await fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(filePath), { recursive: true });
  await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, pdfBytes);
  
  res.set({
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=relatorio.pdf',
    'Content-Length': pdfBytes.length
  });
  
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  stream.pipe(res);
  res.on('finish', async () => {
        // apaga o arquivo do diretório
        await fs.promises.unlink(filePath)});
  });
```

This is my code.

```
error: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "all"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 98,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '47',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'int8.c',
  line: '124',
  routine: 'scanint8'
}
C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:258
        throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + (0, util_js_1.getExceptionMessage)(exceptionDetails));
              ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:16
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:258:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:146:16)
    at async C:\Users\TI\Desktop\carta-api-mesquita\src\config\RenderPdf.js:17:5
```

This is my error.

I tried creating an individual route with all.pdf to see if there were any conflicts with the limit, but it returned the same error.

I have another route but that generates a zip file, it works correctly with the parameter all.

```
This is my code to zip

router.get('/:database/:tipo/:ids/:limite?.zip', async (req, res) => {
    const { database, tipo, ids, limite } = req.params;
  
    let idsArray;
    if (ids === "all") {
      const pool = new Pool({
        user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
        host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
        database: database,
        password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
      });
  
      let query = `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM controle_interno.${tipo} ORDER BY id ASC`;
      if (limite) {
        query += ` LIMIT ${limite}`;
      }
      const result = await pool.query(query);
      idsArray = result.rows.map(row => row.id);
    } else {
      idsArray = ids.split(",");
    }
  
    const zip = new AdmZip();
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
  
    for (let i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
      const id = idsArray[i];
      const url = `http://localhost:${port}/${database}/${tipo}/${id}`;
      console.log(url);
      try {
      await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
      await page.evaluate(() => {
        const button = document.getElementById('gerar-pdf');
        button.remove();
      });
    const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4', printBackground: true, pageRanges: '1' });
      zip.addFile(`${id}.pdf`, pdf, `PDF para o ID ${id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
     }
    }
  
    await browser.close();
    const zipBuffer = zip.toBuffer();
  
    res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${tipo}.zip`,
      'Content-Length': zipBuffer.length
    });
  
    res.send(zipBuffer);
  });
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on, but if `limite` is "all" then the `LIMIT` clause of the query will be incorrect.

Comment: I'll try to change the query to see if I can get some result, maybe it's her.

Comment: I managed to solve it, it was giving route conflict. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, I had a route that generates a pdf individually like: `router.get('/:database/:tipo/:id.pdf'.`

I was using `router.get('/:database/:type/:ids/:limit?.pdf'.` Changing the "ids" to all, it was like: `/:database/:type/all.pdf.`  Causing conflict with the route quoted at the beginning. I changed the end of pdf to pdfs and it solved the problem, thanks everyone.